# To Print the Prime numbers from 1 - 500 and finding the INDEX of the prime numebrs

Tags: java, if-statement

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Integer> Prime_Numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>() ;
    for (int x = 1; x <= 500; x ++) {
        int count = 0;
        for (int y = 2 ; y <= x / 2 ; y ++){
            if (x % y == 0){
                count++;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(count == 0)
            ((ArrayList) Prime_Numbers).add(x);

    }
    System.out.println(Prime_Numbers);
    System.out.println("Enter a prime number from the list");
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int key = sc.nextInt();
    int index =  Arrays.binarySearch((Prime_Numbers.toArray()) , key);
    if(index == key)                             //when index = key its printing %d is not found 
        System.out.printf("%d is found at "+index,key);
    else
        System.out.printf("%d is not found",key);
}
```

I made this Program for my study purpose but i am not quite getting the how the o/p is coming "%d is not found" can anybody give me a hint like how can i fix my code(Facing problem in if condition)

I ran the Program and got the output but in if condition I am not getting excepted Output, eg: if I enter 3 which is prime number and can found be in 2nd index but the O/p gives not found

Comment: `if (index == key)` ?? Maybe `if (index >= 0)`

Comment: Some things not directly related to your problem: don't omit `{` and `}` for "it's just one line of code" things like those if/else statements. You're going to try to put a println in there at some point, and everything will break. Also, you're mixing printf with string concatenation: just use one or the other.  Also, don't cast things that don't need casting: declare your list as `ArrayList<Integer> primeNumbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();`, done, you can add as many `int` values into that without any sort of casting. And on _that_ note, use lowerCamelCase for variable names.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback and thanks for suggesting that it actually worked

Comment: `Arrays.binarySearch (int [] a, int key)` doesn't return `key` if found.  It returns the *index* of `key` in the array -- that is, the  location.  [`Arrays` API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#binarySearch(int[],%20int))

Comment: Some remarks: in Java, variable- and field names should be written in `lowerCamelCase` (`Prime_Numbers` -> `primeNumbers`) --- `List<Integer> Prime_Numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>() ;` unnecessary abstraction, we can use `ArrayList<Integer> ...  = new ArrayList<Integer>();` --- Even if possible, I would highly advice to not skip `{` and `}` on one-line `if`-, `else`-, `for`-, `while`-, ... bodies.

Comment: The cast in `((ArrayList) Prime_Numbers).add(x);` is unnecessary, and actually dangerous: it converts the list reference to a raw type, meaning you lose the type safety of ensuring that only `Integer`s are added to the list. Remove the cast: `PrimeNumbers.add(x);`.

Comment: A couple of points about the prime number finding: 1) 1 isn't a prime number; 2) you don't need to check as many values in the `y` loop: just check all of your previously-found prime numbers by iterating that list: `for (int j : Prime_Numbers) { ... }`.

Comment: @Turing85 "we can use `ArrayList<Integer> ... =`" I disagree, it's far more unusual to declare list variables' types as the concrete type. Rather than this being unnecessary abstraction, I'd say what you're suggesting is unnecessary specificity.

Comment: @AndyTurner if the `List` is created by, e.g., a method call, I would agree. If, however, the `ArrayList` is created in-place, I do not see any benefit in using `List` instead of `ArrayList`.

Comment: @Turing85 the advantage is that you're not tempted to use methods specific to the specific type, which makes it easier to change the implementation you use at a later date. And, if you're not using methods specific to the specific type... just use the general type. (This is covered in Item 64 of _Effective Java_).

Comment: There's a bug in your code: 1 is not a prime number, but your code thinks it is: start your loop from 2 and delete the `if (count == 0)` code block. For a speed up, replace `y <= x / 2` with `y <= Math.sqrt(x)`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using

```
if(index == key)
    System.out.printf("%d is found at "+index,key);
else
    System.out.printf("%d is not found",key);
```

use

```
if(index >= 0)
    System.out.printf("%d is found at "+(index+1),key);
else
    System.out.printf("%d is not found",key);
```

because what `int index =  Arrays.binarySearch((Prime_Numbers.toArray()) , key);` is doing is, it gives the **index** of the search key, if it is contained in the array, **otherwise**, **(-(insertion point) – 1)** where insertion point is the point at which the key would be inserted into the array, i.e., the index of the first element greater than the key, or array.length if all elements in the array are less than the specified key

Answer (score 0):

Use the `indexIf()` method of List:

```
int input = sc.nextInt();
int index = Prime_Numbers.indexOf(input);
if (index >= 0)
    System.out.printf("%d is found at %d\n", input, index);
else
    System.out.printf("%d is not found\n", input);
```

---

Your code is buggy: 1 is not a prime number, and it's way longer than it needs to be. To collect the primes:

```
List<Integer> Prime_Numbers = IntStream.range(2, 501)
  .filter(i -> new BigInteger("" + i).isProbablePrime(10))
  .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Side note: Try to follow Java naming standards. Prefer `primeNumbers` over `Prime_Numbers`.